# How to recover dashboard stickies on macOS Catalina?

Tags: dashboard, catalina, stickies

According to the article [Apple Confirms Dashboard is Going Away After 14 Years](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/06/13/goodbye-dashboard/), dashboard has been removed within macOS 10.15, Catalina. I had some Stickies with information stored in dashboard and I would like to recover it if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are currently a couple known methods to recover stickies (or anything else that was on the dashboard).

1. Stickies from the dashboard have automatically been imported into the Stickies application. Simply open `/Applications/Stickies.app` and they will appear there.
2. All widget save data/preferences are still in the original place. This means that as per https://superuser.com/a/608039, the plist for the dashboard stickies are in `~/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist`.
3. The most obvious: before updating to Catalina copy over your stickies to different place such as text edit or the stickies app.

**Note:** In this file they are stored within html tags that are in HTML Entity form. You can use a converter and then strip tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but instead of Stickies , it was my password manager widget called as Cryptboard. I followed the below steps and it did worked and i was able to recover all my passwords.

**On your update machine which has Catalina --**

1. Copy "widget-com.warptube.widget.CryptBoard.plist" from ~/Library/Preferences
2. Copy "CryptBoard.wdgt" from ~/Library/Widgets
3. Email/Send these 2 files to any other machine which has Mohave

**On machine which has Mohave --**

1. Paste the files in their respective locations where you copy it from in Catalina
2. Go to Dashboard App and Click on "+" sign in bottom left
3. Hooray .. you have the CryptBoard Widget back with all your old Data in it